# when updating user email is blank in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Please can anyone help,

When I update the user from word press admin section user email field is showing blank after the successfully update.

I do not understand why this is happening. Please suggest me what I should check.I am using default user-edit.php
and functions.php are:

```
 <?php
       function register_my_menus() {
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'top-right' => __('Top Right'),
                'footer-menu' => __('Footer Menu'),
                'profile_drive_nav' => __('Profile Drive Page')
            )
        );
    }

    //Top menu Remove Classes
    add_action('init', 'register_my_menus');
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'prefix_nav_menu_args');

    function prefix_nav_menu_args($args = '') {
        $args['container'] = false;
        return $args;
    }

    $menuParameters = array(
        'container' => false,
        'echo' => false,
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
        'depth' => 0,
    );

    //echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
    //Logout Function in Menu perticullar menu--Top Right Menu
    /* add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
      function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
      ob_start();
      wp_loginout('index.php');
      $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      if( $args->theme_location == 'top-right' ){
      $items .= '<li class="login_link">'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
      }
      return $items;
      } */

    //Bloginfo 
    function pk_bloginfo_shortcode($atts) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'key' => '',
        ), $atts));
        return get_bloginfo($key);
    }

    add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
    add_shortcode('bloginfo', 'pk_bloginfo_shortcode');

    //Page Slug Body Classes
    function add_body_class($pk_classes) {
        global $post;
        if (isset($post)) {
            $pk_classes[] = /* $post->post_type . '-' . */ $post->post_name;
        }

        return $pk_classes;
    }

    add_filter('body_class', 'add_body_class');


    /* Remove Checkout Fields */
    /* Remove Woocommerce User Fields */
    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
    add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_override_billing_fields');
    add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'custom_override_shipping_fields');

    function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
        //unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);  
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_company']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_city']);
        unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
        return $fields;
    }

    function custom_override_billing_fields($fields) {
        unset($fields['billing_state']);
        unset($fields['billing_country']);
        unset($fields['billing_company']);
        unset($fields['billing_address_1']);
        unset($fields['billing_address_2']);
        unset($fields['billing_postcode']);
        unset($fields['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['account_password']);

        return $fields;
    }

    function custom_override_shipping_fields($fields) {
        unset($fields['shipping_first_name']);
        unset($fields['shipping_last_name']);
        unset($fields['shipping_state']);
        unset($fields['shipping_country']);
        unset($fields['shipping_company']);
        unset($fields['shipping_address_1']);
        unset($fields['shipping_address_2']);
        unset($fields['shipping_postcode']);
        unset($fields['shipping_city']);
        unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
        return $fields;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_address_fields32');

    function override_address_fields32($fields) {
        //$address_fields['account_password']['placeholder'] = '';
        $address_fields['first_name']['label'] = 'Name';
        $address_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = '';
        return $address_fields;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );

    function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {

        $fields['billing_email']    = array(
            'label'          => __('Email', 'woothemes'),
            'required'       => true
             );
        return $fields;
    }

    /*
      add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_address_fields32');
      function override_address_fields32( $fields ) {
      //$address_fields['account_password']['placeholder'] = '';
      $address_fields['billing_first_name']['label']   ='Name';
      $address_fields['billing_first_name']['required']   =true;
      $address_fields['billing_email']['label']   ='Email';
      $address_fields['billing_email']['required']   =true;
      $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = '';
      $address_fields['city']['placeholder'] = '';
      $address_fields['state']['placeholder'] = '';
      $address_fields['postcode']['placeholder'] = '';
      return $address_fields;
      }
      /* End - Remove Woocommerce User Fields */

    add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text');
    add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

    function translate_text($translated) {
        $translated = str_ireplace('Billing Details', 'Sign Up', $translated);
        return $translated;
    }

    add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text2');
    add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text2');

    function translate_text2($translated2) {
        $translated2 = str_ireplace('Additional Information', '', $translated2);
        return $translated2;
    }

    add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text3');
    add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text3');

    function translate_text3($translated3) {
        $translated3 = str_ireplace('First Name', 'Name', $translated3);
        return $translated3;
    }

    add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text4');
    add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text4');

    function translate_text4($translated4) {
        $translated4 = str_ireplace('Create an account by entering the information below. If you are a returning customer please login at the top of the page.', '<hr style="clear:both;" />', $translated4);
        return $translated4;
    }

    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);
    /** woocommerce: change position of add-to-cart on single product * */
    //Removed featured image
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20);


    //For pricing hook
    remove_action('woocommerce_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_price', 10);
    add_action('woocommerce_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_price', 25);


    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 7);


    //Remove return customer
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10);


    // place the following code in your theme's functions.php file
    // Add a second password field to the checkout page.
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init', 'wc_add_confirm_password_checkout', 10, 1);

    function wc_add_confirm_password_checkout($checkout) {
        if (get_option('woocommerce_registration_generate_password') == 'no') {
            $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password2'] = array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'label' => __('Confirm password', 'woocommerce'),
                'placeholder' => __('Confirm password', 'woocommerce'),
                'required' => true
            );
        }
    }

    // Check the password and confirm password fields match before allow checkout to proceed.
    add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout', 10, 2);

    function wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout($posted) {
        $checkout = WC()->checkout;
        if (!is_user_logged_in() && ( $checkout->must_create_account || !empty($posted['createaccount']) )) {
            if (strcmp($posted['account_password'], $posted['account_password2']) !== 0) {
                wc_add_notice(__('Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce'), 'error');
            }
        }
    }
    /* Changes the redirect URL for the Return To Shop button in the cart. */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'wp_set_timezone' );

    // Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
    function wp_set_timezone( $fields ) {
        $fields['billing']['billing_timezone'] = array(
            'label'     => __('Timezone', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder'   => _x('Timezone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required'  => false,
            'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
            'clear'     => true,
            'type'      => 'radio',
            'options'     => array('UK'=>'UK','NON-UK'=>'NON-UK'
            )//end of options
        );

        return $fields;
    }
    function wc_empty_cart_redirect_url() {
        return bloginfo('url') . '/?page_id=14';
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'wc_empty_cart_redirect_url');

    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_save_timezone');

    function woo_save_timezone($order_id) {
        if ($_POST['timezone'])
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'timezone', esc_attr($_POST['timezone']));
    }



    /**
     * Store terms and conditions value within the database
     * */
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_save_terms_and_conditions_status');

    /* function woo_save_terms_and_conditions_status( $order_id ) {
      if ($_POST['terms']) update_post_meta( $order_id, '_terms', esc_attr($_POST['terms']));
      }

      add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'woo_display_terms_and_conditions_status', 10, 1 );
     */

    function woo_display_terms_and_conditions_status($order) {
        $terms = get_post_meta($order->id, '_terms', true);
        $terms_status = ( $terms == 'on' ? __('accepted') : __('undefined') );
        echo '<p><strong>' . __('Terms & conditions') . ':</strong> ' . $terms_status . '</p>';
    }

    //Remove sidebar from product page
    remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);

    //Thank You Title Messages change here
    /* function bk_title_order_received( $title, $id ) {
      if ( is_order_received_page() && get_the_ID() === $id ) {
      $title = "Thank you for your order!";
      }

      return $title;
      }

      add_filter( 'the_title', 'bk_title_order_received', 10, 2 );
     */

    //Remove Related Products
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);


    //Remove Tabs
    add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98);

    function woo_remove_product_tabs($tabs) {

        //unset( $tabs['description'] );
        unset($tabs['reviews']);
        return $tabs;
    }

    function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields($return, $product) {
        return true;
    }

    show_admin_bar(false);

    /* Adding Image Upload Fields */

    function get_image_url($user) {
        if (esc_url(get_the_author_meta('user_meta_image', $user->ID))) {
            return esc_url(get_the_author_meta('user_meta_image', $user->ID));
        } else {
            return esc_url(bloginfo('template_url') . "/images/user-img.jpg");
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    add_editor_style('editor-style.css');

    function deleteDirectoryFile($checkDirectoryExist) {
        foreach (glob($checkDirectoryExist . "/*.*") as $filename) {
            if (is_file($filename)) {
                @unlink($filename);
            }
        }
        @rmdir($dir);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    add_editor_style('css/custom-editor-style.css');

    add_action('media_buttons', 'add_my_media_button');

    function add_my_media_button() {
        if (!current_user_can('subscriber')){
            echo '<a href="#" id="insert-my-media" class="button">Add my media</a>';
        }

    }

    function add_media_upload_scripts() {
        if (is_admin()) {
            return;
        }
        wp_enqueue_media();
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_media_upload_scripts');

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'restrict_font_choices');

    function restrict_font_choices($initArray) {
        $initArray['theme_advanced_fonts'] = 'Andale Mono=andale mono,times;' .
                'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;' .
                'Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;' .
                'Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;' .
                'Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;' .
                'Courier New=courier new,courier;' .
                'Georgia=georgia,palatino;' .
                'Helvetica=helvetica;' .
                'Impact=impact,chicago;' .
                'Symbol=symbol;' .
                'Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;' .
                'Terminal=terminal,monaco;' .
                'Times New Roman=times new roman,times;' .
                'Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;' .
                'Verdana=verdana,geneva;' .
                'Webdings=webdings;' .
                'Calibri=Calibri' .
                'Formula436B=Formula436B' .
                'Lucida Calligraphy=Lucida Calligraphy';
        return $initArray;
    }

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (current_user_can('customer') && !current_user_can('upload_files'))
        add_action('admin_init', 'allow_customer_uploads');

    function allow_customer_uploads() {
        $contributor = get_role('customer');
        $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
    }
    function add_theme_caps() {
        // gets the subscriber role
        $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );

        // would allow the subscriber role to upload photos for the current theme
        $role->add_cap( 'upload_files' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');

    ///////////////////////////overwrite user login///////////////////////////////////////

    function wcs_filter_username_email($args) {
        $args['user_login'] = $args['user_email'];
        return $args;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'wcs_filter_username_email');

    ////////////////////////////////Code for free user//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    require('class-wev-email-verification.php');
    $wev = new WEV_Email_Verification();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_save_terms_and_conditions_status');

    function woo_save_terms_and_conditions_status($order_id) {
        if ($_POST['terms'])
            update_post_meta($order_id, '_terms', esc_attr($_POST['terms']));
    }

    function add_user_to_laravel($order_id) {
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $postId = $order->post->ID;
        $wpUserId = get_post_meta($postId, '_customer_user', true);
        $wpUser = get_userdata($wpUserId);
        /* Add user into laravel */
        $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

        $wpdbNew = new wpdb(DMS_DB_USER, DMS_DB_PASSWORD, DMS_DB_NAME, DMS_DB_HOST);
        $qry = "SELECT email,id FROM users WHERE email = '$wpUser->user_email'";
        $userExist = $wpdbNew->get_results( $qry );

        if( empty($userExist) ){
            $wpdbNew->insert("users", array(
                'group_id' => '2',
                'parent_id' => '0',
                'username' => $wpUser->user_email,
                'email' => $wpUser->user_email,
                'password' => '',
                'status' => get_user_meta($wpUserId, 'is_activated', true),
                'network' => '0',
                'token' => '',
                'remember_token' => '',
                'wp_user_id' => $wpUserId,
                'created_at' => $currentDateTime,
                'updated_at' => $currentDateTime,
                'timezone'=>get_user_meta($wpUserId, 'billing_timezone', true),
            ));
            $userId = $wpdbNew->insert_id;
            $wpdbNew->insert("user_profile", array(
                'user_id' => $userId,
                'first_name' => $wpUser->display_name,
                'last_name' => '',
                'email' => $wpUser->user_email,
                'company' => '',
                'position' => '',
                'website' => '',
                'mobile' => '',
                'image' => '',
            ));

            $constArr = array(DMS_FIRST_DEFAULT_NETWORK_ORDER => array(
                DMS_FIRST_DEFAULT_NETWORK, DMS_FIRST_DEFAULT_NETWORK_COLOR)
            );
            foreach ($constArr as $k => $v) {
                $wpdbNew->insert("user_networks", array(
                    'id' => NULL,
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'name' => $v[0],
                    'color' => $v[1],
                    'can_delete' => 0,
                    'created_on' => $currentDateTime,
                    'order_by' => $k
                ));
            }

            // update user notification settings.
            $wpdbNew->insert("user_settings", array(
                'user_id' => $userId,
                'notifyon_share_folder' => 1,
                'notifyon_document_change' => 1,
                'notifyon_shared_document_deleted' => 1
            ));

            /* End */

        }else{
            $userId = $userExist[0]->id;
            //$query = "UPDATE users SET wp_user_id= $wpUserId WHERE id = $userId";

            $wpdbNew->update(
                "users",
                array(
                    'wp_user_id' => $wpUserId
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => $userId
                ),
                $format = null,
                $where_format = null
            );
            // $wpdbNew->get_results( $query );
        }
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $package_name = $item['name'];
            $amount = $item['line_total'];
            $start_date = $item['subscription_start_date'];
            $end_date = $item['subscription_end_date'];
            $status = $item['subscription_status'];
        }

        $wpdbNew->insert("user_subscriptions", array(
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'package_name' => $package_name,
            'total_amount' => $amount,
            'start_date' => $start_date,
            'end_date' => $end_date,
            'status' => get_user_meta($wpUserId, 'is_activated', true),
            'cancelled_on' => '',
            'disk_space' => get_post_meta($product_id, 'disk_space', true)
        ));

    }

    add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'add_user_to_laravel');

    add_filter ('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'my_change_status_function');
    function my_change_status_function ($order_id) {
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        //Do whatever additional logic you like before….
        return 'completed';
    }

    function my_custom_login() {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/css/custom-login-styles.css" >';
    }

    add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');

    function update_text() {
        return $thank_you_message = sprintf(__(''));
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_subscriptions_thank_you_message', 'update_text');

    function previewEmail() {

        if (is_admin()) {
            $default_path = WC()->plugin_path() . '/templates/';

            $files = scandir($default_path . 'emails');
            $exclude = array('.', '..', 'email-header.php', 'email-footer.php', 'plain');
            $list = array_diff($files, $exclude);
            ?><form method="get" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="order" value="942">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="previewemail">
            <select name="file">
                <?php foreach ($list as $item) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $item; ?>"><?php echo str_replace('.php', '', $item); ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select><input type="submit" value="Go"></form><?php
            global $order;
            $order = new WC_Order($_GET['order']);
            echo'<pre>';
            print_r($order);
            echo'<pre>';
            //die($order->billing_email);
            wc_get_template('emails/email-header.php', array('order' => $order));


            wc_get_template('emails/' . $_GET['file'], array('order' => $order));
            wc_get_template('emails/email-footer.php', array('order' => $order));
        }
        return null;
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_previewemail', 'previewEmail');

    /* add media frontend bof */

    /* add media frontend eof */

    /* hook update user bof */
    /* send email template when admin update user details */

    /*function admin_update_user($user_id, $old_user_data) {
        //die('22222');
        $userDtl = get_userdata($user_id);
        $pass1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pass1');
        $pass2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pass2');

        if (!empty($pass1) && $pass1 === $pass2 && sanitize_text_field($pass1) === $pass1):
            $userPassword = sanitize_text_field($pass1);
        else:
            $userPassword = 'Your chosen password';
        endif;

        if (current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {

            ob_start();
            include_once('woocommerce/emails/email-header.php');
            include_once('woocommerce/emails/user-account-updated.php');
            include_once('woocommerce/emails/email-footer.php');
            $message = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

            wp_mail($userDtl->user_email, 'Your K-Docs account is activated', $message, $headers);
        }
    }*/

    function wpse_user_update($user_id) {
        if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
            //die('$user_id-'.$user_id);
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            //echo'<pre>';
            //print_r($userDtl);
            $pass1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pass1');
            $pass2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pass2');
            $uemail2 = strlen($user_info->user_email)>0?$user_info->user_email:$user_info->user_login;
            if (!empty($pass1) && $pass1 === $pass2 && sanitize_text_field($pass1) === $pass1):
                $userPassword = sanitize_text_field($pass1);
            else:
                $userPassword = 'Your chosen password';
            endif;
            if (current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
                ob_start();
                include_once('woocommerce/emails/email-header.php');
                include_once('woocommerce/emails/user-account-updated.php');
                include_once('woocommerce/emails/email-footer.php');
                $message = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
                wp_mail($uemail2, 'Your K-Docs account is updaed', $message, $headers);
            }
        }
    }

    add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'wpse_user_update');
    add_action('personal_options_update', 'wpse_user_update');
    /* hook update user eof */


        ?>
```

Comment: Post your code. so we can help you

Comment: @AnkurBhadania Edited Please check and help me

Comment: post your code  not wordpress default file

Comment: only this code I am using and functions.php code also pasted please look